# Facing issue to show am pm from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs, daterangepicker

I am using daterangerpicker and moment.js for the daterange. Now when I am passing values from database to daterangepicker it is taking some default timestamp. Initially I try to look in the daterangepicker format but didn't got any help. Later I try to explore moment.js method still didn't got any luck

These values I check on browser console

dateFormat
"MM-DD-YYYY hh a"

$(this).val()
"11/06/2020 05 PM"

But somehow the 5pm is getting convert into 12am. Below is my code

```
var dateFormat = $(this).data("date-format") || "MM/DD/YYYY hh A";
  
var currentDate = $(this).val().length > 1 ? moment($(this).val(), dateFormat)._d : null;
$(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");

var dates = $(this).daterangepicker(
  {
    singleDatePicker: true,
    locale: {
      format: dateFormat
    }
  },
  function(start, end, label)
  {
    $(this).val(start.format(dateFormat));
  }
);
if(currentDate && currentDate != 'Invalid Date'){
  dates.daterangepicker( { startDate: currentDate } );
}
dates.daterangepicker({ singleDatePicker: true, showDropdowns: true, autoApply: false, timePicker: true, minDate: Abc.getAdminMinDateTime(), locale: { format: dateFormat} });
```

Daterangepicker version 3.0.5
Moment.js 2.18.1

Comment: looks like a timezone issue

Comment: @AbishekKumar It is not a timezone issue

Comment: You should use `format` if you want a date string. Instead, you are using `_d`, which is not documented anywhere in moment.js docs and since it is for internal usage inside library and subject to changes, it may lead you to wrong results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the solution. THe reason it was not working because $(this).daterangepicker when we call daterangepicker it will create a new object

```
var dateFormat = $(this).data("date-format") || "MM/DD/YYYY hh A";
  
var currentDate = $(this).val().length > 1 ? moment($(this).val(), dateFormat)._d : null;


$(this).attr("autocomplete", "off");
  var date_options = {
    singleDatePicker: true,
    showDropdowns: true,
    autoApply: false,
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: Abc.getAdminMinDateTime(),
    locale: { format: dateFormat }
  }
  if(currentDate && currentDate != 'Invalid Date'){
    date_options["startDate"] = currentDate;
  }
  var dates = $(this).daterangepicker(date_options, function(start, end, label){
    $(this).val(start.format(dateFormat));
  });
```